# Setting ToolTip for DataGridCell in ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf

Given a `UserControl` which features a `DataGrid`, with a column defined as follows;

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=MyStringProperty}"/>
```

And a resource dictionary applied to the `UserControl` which defines a style for `DataGridCell`;

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
```

Is it possible to apply a tool-tip to the cell that uses the bound value?

I've tried;

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding}" />
</Style>
```

I naively assumed that the binding at this point would be the value of `MyStringProperty`, because I thought that setting a binding on a parent item would affect the binding of the child item (i.e. the cell), but it actually seems to be the binding of the overall row.

Is there some way to reference the object which is bound to the column from the cell's style setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataContext` in `DataGridCell` should be the same as in `DataGridTextColumn`. So in this case if you want the tooltip to be the cell content, try binding to the `Content` property like this:

```
 <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=Content,
                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Comment: So, the problem is that I have multiple DataGridTextColumns that all bind to different properties of the overall row's datacontext. So putting in the exact name in the tool-tip setter isn't going to work for me - I need an approach that is generic. Is that possible?

Comment: @ChristopherMcAtackney I edited the code a little, not tested it, please try it.

Comment: Hm, that actually shows the literal path name as the tool tip then (e.g. "ErrorDetails", instead of the value bound to the cell). Is there a way to coerce the actual value I wonder..

Comment: @ChristopherMcAtackney again, just updated it (2 snippets). I'm not sure about the first, but the second should work.

Comment: that actually works now, but bizarrely it makes the content of the cell disappear once the tool tip has displayed. I'll do more research into this and post back my findings.

Comment: @ChristopherMcAtackney I think you mean about the second snippet (the first does not work?). Well, looks like the cell Content is actually a `FrameworkElement`, once it's added to the Tooltip, it will be removed first from the DataGridCell. You can try using some `Converter` to convert the `Content` to a string (which will be the Tooltip's Content).

Comment: The converter approach didn't seem to work because the FrameworkElements (e.g. TextBlock) didn't have any values in them at the time the converter executed. I think I'm just going to go for an alternative approach where I have one tool-tip for the entire row, because I'm going round in circles with this and don't want to hassle you any more about it. Cheers for your time though!